# How to create relationships in my code first with existing database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have tried looking for answers and though I am sure my question has been answered somewhere, I failed to get the answer. 
I have two tables independent but related. I am dealing with my classes in EF.
I want to create a model in c# with none or one to many relationship.
How do I do that in code?
Below are my two models:

```
public class adult
{
        [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} cannot exceed {1} characters")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set;}
    public string Address1 {get; set;}
    public string Address2 {get; set;} 
 }
```

Below is the second model with many 'children'.

```
 public class children
{
    [Key]
    public int childNo { get; set; }
    public string favourite { get; set; }
    **public int childID { get; set; }**

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} cannot exceed {1} characters")]
    public string colour { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateReceived { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePaid { get; set; }
}
```

I am interested in a none or one to many relationship i.e I can have an adult without a child. 
The childID in the children class corresponds to the ID in adult class. We have none or one ID in class matching with many childID in the children class. How do I model this in my class? I am also interested in displaying those mapped  values in one view and edit, create and save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that Entity Framework Code first creates relationships such as one-to-one, one-to-many, and many-to-many itself only by some coding.
And by using Virtual Properties you can navigate between two models,so add code bellow to your first model :

```
public virtual ICollection<children> children_{ get; set;}
```

Then into the second model add this :

```
[Required]
public virtual adult adult_{ get; set;}
```

This represents one-to-many relationship between children and adult. [Required] Ensures that any child surely has a parent(adult) so it cannot be null.
Notice that there's no need to adding relational ID of the other models in current model. So using this part of code is not generally used:

```
public int childID {get; set;}
```

If you want to use the above code in 2nd model,No Navigation will appear in DB. must mount it manually in controller and navigate tables in your codes like controller.But, by using virtual properties EF generates relation key like this to navigate between models.After using this technique, see your tables, you will find a column named childID in adult table created by EF automatically.

Comment: Thanks Amir fo your response. How does my EF model know that childID is related to ID in adult class?

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. I have made those changes and I need to test if its working. From my question you will notice I asked how can I show those values on my view.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as calling a member. For example when you want to know which children are related to specific adult you may use a code like this:

```
var childno = db.adult.child.ChildNo;
```

or for searching :

```
string favor = db.adult.child.Find(input.id).Select(s => s.favourite).ToString();
```

child model now is a member of adult, and adults may have some children in their ICollection of child.